# use forloop.counter0 to index an array in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to access the contents of an array using `forloop.counter0` in django templates but I can't get it working.

What I have is

```
{% for action in my_action_list %}
    {{another_list.forloop.counter0}}
{% endfor %}
```

Where `my_action_list` is a list and `another_list` is also a list.  I have tried doing this manually e.g. `{{another_list.0}}` and this works and I have also tried `{{forloop.counter0}}` and this is printing out the correct index so not sure why its not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: I was also wondering how to do this. What I really need is an indexof equivalent from javascript in django template so that I can access my conditional indice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The templating engine is probably looking for a property called `another_list.forloop`, which of course doesn't exist.

If you want to loop through two lists simultaneously, the best solution may be to `zip` them in your view beforehand.

Comment: +1: Do as much as possible in the view function.  If the template gets complex, fix the view function.